# Snap or group text in textfield/textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

Some applications and websites have a feature where text is grouped and snapped into a single element, and can only be deleted as a whole. Examples are e-mail addresses in e-mail clients, or tags in photosites and below in the stackoverflow tags box. As soon as you type a space after the text, it is replaced with and visualized as a block, sometimes including a cross to delete it. I was wondering if there is a common name for this, and if there is a jquery or related implementation that I can use out of the box.

Comment: Check the tagit jQuery plugin http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I am looking for. I'm already using right now! I can't mark this to be the answer though, as you wrote it as a comment instead of an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the **[tagit jQuery plugin at Git Hub..](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/)**